# Manually add data to MySQL query array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I've just started using Codeigniter, and am loving MVC. I have a simple mysql query in a model that returns an array of rows to my controller.

```
$query = $this->db->get('shows');
return $query->result();
```

Date information is stored in the database as mysql date `(yyyy-mm-dd)` and I explode to get month `mm` and day `dd`.

What I'm wondering is, is there any way to manually add the variables for month and day of each row to the query result using a simple foreach? I know I could manually add each database field's value to an array, and include the month and day variables, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way of inserting them into the already existing array created by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@slier had the code, but below is transformed to codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("*, MONTH(date_column) as date_month, DAY(date_column) as date_day");
$query = $this->db->get('shows');
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I'd actually come across that method of pulling the month and day, but the post I read said that it couldn't be combined with `SELECT *` so I started looking elsewhere. Thanks @Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

Ok im not familiar with codeigniter, but if you want to get month and day in raw mysql you can simply do something like below

```
$sql = 'SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, DAY(date) AS day FROM shows';
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Im assuming your date column is in `date` dataype